# How can I append a list object in dynamodb with AWS Amplify and Graphql

Tags: list, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify

When I execute this mutation query (with review id 5) I expect that, when ID 5 is not in the array list, that this will be added to the dynamodb Reviews (type List). But instead the complete Reviews will be overwritten with this object

How can I append or update specific values in de DynamoDB Reviews list array?

```
  mutation CreateUser{
    updateObject(input:{id:"d77d2ec2-b4a3-43b7-bb0e-9ef6f1e6fd76", reviews: [{
      id:5
      score: 8
      description: "Ramon11"
      email:"jan1111@jan.nl"
    }] })
    {
        id
        name
        reviews {
          id
        }
    }
}

**In my schema this code is there:** 
type Object @model @searchable{
  id: ID!
  reviews: [Review]
  profile: Profile @connection
}


type Review{
  id: ID!
  score: Int!
  description: String!
  email: String!
}
```